# Identification of book set in Ancient Egypt

Tags: identification-request

A couple years ago, I read a book which I would like to revisit.

I don't remember much, but here's what I have.

- Setting is Ancient Egypt
- One of the primary characters is a Pharaoh or other reputable monarch (definitely female)
- Religion is a major aspect of the book
- Plot may have been a mystery
- A general or important leader in battle was commanded to (graphic/mature)

  > *remove the penises of the fallen enemy soldiers as a political display... I think they were collected in a basket*. I remember this vividly because it was surprising in the story.
- The characters visited a [necropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necropolis)
- The reading level / lexile level is high / relatively complex
- A brief search brings up [Nefertiti](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060765917) and [The Assassins of Isis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0755307828) as potential starting places (?) but these authors have also written **many** similar works which may be of no relation.
- The book was written before 2014, in English. It was in the public, town library.

Comment: This sounds as though it could be a non-fiction work.  The practices of which you speak were performed during some periods of the Egyptian empire.

Comment: @Chenmunka it may have been based on a non-fiction event or person, I'm not sure, but it was definitely told as a narrative

Comment: Could I get some feedback? This question received five upvotes close to being posted but two downvotes have since appeared. I am completely willing to change the question to fit the site's standards but I can't do so without knowing what's wrong.

Comment: @Zxyrra there will be some people that down vote ALL id questions, no matter what.  heck, there are people that'll down vote questions that are high quality.  so in general, unless your question is down voted into the negatives, your question is typically ok.  if it's terrible it'll be down voted into oblivion or voted to close.

Comment: @DForck42 From my experience on SE two downvotes with only 20 views is not healthy

Comment: but anyway, with id questions we want the asker to provide as much detail up front as possible.  basically stating: where you read it, what language was it in, country of origin, whatever plot points you can remember, etc.  you did a good job of covering as much as you could

Comment: @Zxyrra consider that this is a private beta still, there are more active voters compared to the total population. (i.e. more votes cast per number of views)

Comment: VTC: Seems too broad, unclear if fiction/non-fiction, "*religion is a major aspect*" seems too broad as well, etc.

Comment: I upvoted and reviewed as Leave Open, but I do think this question could benefit from some more detail, if there's anything you happen to recall. On the other hand, if you'd add stuff you're not certain about, maybe it's better to stick to certainty.

Comment: @Emrakul I have done the same.

Comment: Could this be Mika Waltari's 'The Egyptian' ? Written in 1979, I think it might meet most of the conditions (but I fin the list of conditions rather general).